# Slicer doesn't work correctly when pivot data refreshed

Tags: excel

Does anyone have experience with using slicers on Excel? I am creating an excel template where the user should be able to drop in new data, click on refresh datasource for predefined pivot tables and reconnect the slicers.

When I try this myself, the pivots update but the slicers don't seem to accurately filter - they work on 1 pivot table but not the other. I am not sure where I am going wrong! Unfortunately as it's proprietary info I can't provide a screenshot/example.

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

I have tried refreshing the pivot tables and slicers, made sure that the source data is the same (just changed the number of rows I look at in the pivot for the test). Slicers worked fine when they were initially setup.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "reconnect the slicers"? If the slicers were fine when initially setup, there was no need to touch them.

Comment: in order to refresh the data I need to remove the connections, change the datasource to include additional rows, update the pivots and reattach the slicers onto the existing pivots.

Comment: Have you even tried to refresh without removing the connections? I, for one, do not need to detach anything so I would say you have not. Or it means you are doing things a different way than is possible, in which case you have to precisely describe how you create your objects.

Comment: I obviously tried that first which is why I ended up needed to disconnect the slicer. When they are connected I get the error I have attached to the original post.

Comment: And you are right-clicking on each slicer and using Report Connections to link them to the desired Pivot Tables?

Comment: I think you're not just refreshing but instead are trying to change the source of one of your pivot table. A slicer needs the several pivot tables it is connected to, to have the same source, which means you cannot change the source of one, then change the source of the other pivot table. When users "drop in new data", do you mean they drop a new file (thus needs to redirect the connections to the new file name)?

Comment: One solution is to use a name (menu Formulas > Name manager), so you never change the source of your pivot tables but rather what it points to (which applies **simultaneously** to all the pivot tables as a result). Another possibility would be to import external data to a table (e.g. in a hidden sheet), then connect your pivot tables to that simple table, which again makes it so the source of your pivot tables is never edited 1 by 1.

Comment: the user copies and paste the data onto a hidden sheet, the issue is that I can't account for the number of rows for the pivot so I was hoping to record a macro to redefine the range of the pivot depending on the number of rows for that specific data range. The number of columns and type of data is always the same, just not the #rows

Comment: Menu Home > Format as table creates tables that grow with the number of rows automatically. When you do that, it automatically creates a name too, so you will have to change the source of the pivot tables manually once (to use the name rather than the cells addresses), then the name will do exactly what I described without issues.

Comment: I've just tried this and the slicer isn't filtering both table correctly, it works on one but not the other... any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked Right click on the slicer > report connections (of course, first make sure the source of both pivot tables is the name of the range formatted as a table, by default `Table1[#All]`)?

Comment: yep, I have renamed the table just to be on the safe side and tried to remove existing slicers and recreate them just in case but no joy

Comment: ... and report connections? Unless you add some more screenshots showing how the pivot tables and slicer are configured, that is where I am starting to be blocked.